# differences between gem file on local & heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems, facebooker2

I'm using the following gem in an app  -

https://github.com/dekart/facebooker2

It seems to be rendering different javascript on my local machine than when deployed to server -

My local version looks like this -

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        FB.init({
          appId  : 'MYAPPID',
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
          channelUrl : 'http://MYLOCALURL.local/channel.html'
        });
```

The version on heroku looks like this -

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        FB.init({
          appId  : 'MYAPPID',
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML  - NO COMMA HERE CAUSING JS BUG
          channelUrl : 'https://MYLIVEURL.heroku.com/channel.html'
        });
```

In the heroku version, the javascript is missing a comma and thus causing a bug that stops the login button from displaying.

I've included the gem in my gem file like this -

```
gem 'facebooker2', :git=>"https://github.com/dekart/facebooker2.git"
```

Any idea why there would be this difference?

Comment: Can you show use the line in your Gemfile where you require that gem.  By guess you are not being specific enough in your gemfile

Comment: added to the question, thanks for looking at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my server and now local & heroku are the same.